# How can I set blob properties without overriding existing properties?

Tags: php, azure, azure-storage

This is my current code:

```
$opts = new SetBlobPropertiesOptions();
$opts->setContentDisposition('attachment');
$result = $blobClient->setBlobProperties($container, $path, $opts);
```

This works fine to set a property, but overrides other properties (such as content-type).

I've tried something like the following (before the code above) but the function doesn't exist:

```
$opts = $blobClient->getBlobProperties($container, $path);
$opts->setContentDisposition('attachment');
```

Any thoughts?

Comment: https://github.com/Azure/azure-storage-php/blob/master/src/Blob/Models/GetBlobPropertiesResult.php

Comment: https://github.com/Azure/azure-storage-php/blob/master/src/Blob/BlobRestProxy.php#L2730

Answer (score 0):

There are something similar, you can try with the following code snippet:

```
$result = $blobClient->getBlobProperties($container, $path);
$opts = new SetBlobPropertiesOptions($result->getProperties());
$opts->setContentDisposition('attachment');
$result = $blobClient->setBlobProperties($container, $path, $opts);
```

This should do the job.